# RegEx skip word

Tags: regex, pcregrep

I would like to use regular expressions to extract the first couple of words and the second to last letter of a string.
For example, in the string

```
                       "CSC 101 Intro to Computing  A  R"
```

I would like to capture

```
                        "CSC 101 A"
```

Maybe something similar to this

```
                 grep -o -P '\w{3}\s\d{3}*thenIdon'tKnow*\s\w\s'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
^((?:\w+\W+){2}).*(\w+)\W+\w+$
```

And use group 1 + 2, see it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/csxWFd/1).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^                 # match the start of the line/string
(                 # capture group 1
    (?:\w+\W+){2} # repeated non-capturing group with words/non words
)
.*                # anything else afterwards
(\w+)\W+\w+       # backtracking to the second last word character
$
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The regular expression works but how do I only print group 1 & 2?

Comment: @IBWEV: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using pcregrep, grep, and possibly sed of the GNU utilities.

Answer (score 0):

A whole RegEx pattern can't match disjointed groups.

I suggest taking a look at Capture Groups - basically you capture the two disjointed groups, the matched couples of words can then be used by referring to these two groups.

`grep` can't print out multiple capture groups so an example with `sed` is
`echo 'CSC 101 Intro to Computing  A  R' | sed -n 's/^\(\w\{3\}\s[[:digit:]]\{3\}\).*\?\(\w\)\s\+\w$/\1 \2/p'` which prints out `CSC 101 A`
Note that the pattern used here is [`^(\w{3}\s\d{3}).*?(\w)\s+\w$`](https://regex101.com/r/lok2jb/3)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The command you have written works nicely at the command prompt.  However, it is not working in my script

Comment: pcregrep -M 'LSUS(\n|.)*?of' $f                         |
 grep -P '(\w{3}|\w{4})\s\d{3}\s.{23}\s+[ABCD]'    |
 grep -o -P '(?<=).{40}(?=)'                               |
 sed -n 's/^\(\w\{3\}\s[[:digit:]]\{3\}\).*\?\w\s\+\(\w\)$/\1 \2/p'

Comment: What does `pcregrep -M 'LSUS(\n|.)*?of' $f | grep -P '(\w{3}|\w{4})\s\d{3}\s.{23}\s+[ABCD]' | grep -o -P '(?<=).{40}(?=)'` print out? You may want to modify the sed part to `sed -n 's/^\(\w\{3,4\}\s[[:digit:]]\{3\}\).*\?\(\w\)$/\1 \2/p'` to match your format

Comment: It prints out   "CSC 101 Intro to Computing  A  R"  .  I would like to capture "CSC 101 A" .   I am close to understanding the regular expression you have following sed but what does "\?" do?

Comment: I got it because of your help.   sed -n 's/^\(\w\{3,4\}\s[[:digit:]]\{3\}\).*\(\w\)/\1 \2/p'  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
^(\S+)\s+(\S+).*(\S+)\s+\S+$
```

- The 3 captured groups capture the 3 desired potions
- `\S` indicates any non-whitespace character
- `\s` indicates any whitespace character

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/47gn73/1)

---

As you have used `grep` with PCRE in your example, i am assuming you have access to the GNU toolset. Using GNU `sed`:

```
% sed -E 's/^(\S+)\s+(\S+).*(\S+)\s+\S+$/\1 \2 \3/' <<<"CSC 101 Intro to Computing  A  R"
CSC 101 A
```

Comment: How do I only print the captured groups?